# Calculating the limit $L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+\sin(y)^2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

$$L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+\sin(y)^2}.$$

I want to prove that the limit does not exist.

I take a first path $y=0$ leads to  .
So $L= lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cdot 0}{x^2+\sin(0)^2}=0$.

I take a second path $x=sin(y)$ leads to $$L=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin y\cdot y}{\sin(y)^2+\sin(y)^2}=1/2.$$

My question is it enough to write paths such I did, must I add something, like $x\neq 0$ in the first path and $y\neq 0$ in the second path?

Comment: What you did is sufficient.  In order for the limit to exist, it has to be the same for all paths.  Being different on two paths is sufficient to negate.

Comment: The question is not well formulated. One needs to specify the domain of definition of the function and you have to make sure the path lies in the domain of definition.

Comment: Using poolar coordinates is useful in most double limit problems. For different theta you can get diff values.

Comment: Yes, but I read somewhere that it is useful to use it for calculating limits but not showing that it does not exist..

Comment: If you find two angles that give different values of the limit it means that the limit doesnt exist. Its totally opposite in my opinion. Its great to spot whether the limit will exist. If you end up with costheta at the end you know for sure it doesnt exist. IF you end up with t*cos(theta) , t-->0 it exists..

Answer (score 2):

Consider the curves $\gamma_{1}(t) = (t,t)$ and $\gamma_{2}(t) = (t,-t)$.

On one hand, the limit along $\gamma_{1}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{2}}{t^{2} + \sin^{2}(t)} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{1 + \dfrac{\sin^{2}(t)}{t^{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the limit along $\gamma_{2}$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-t^{2}}{t^{2} + \sin^{2}(t)} = \lim_{t\to 0}-\frac{1}{1 + \dfrac{\sin^{2}(t)}{t^{2}}} = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Hence the proposed limit does not exist.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi @APCorreia thanks when taking as i did a path y=0, must i say that $x\neq 0$?

Comment: Hello @Usermat ! When we study the limit of some function near the point $(0,0)$, we are interested in its behavior arbitrarily near to it, but not necessarily equal to $(0,0)$. When you fix $y = 0$, we are approaching $(0,0)$ along the horizontal axis, where we assume that $x\neq 0$. Consequently your assumption is valid. Hopefully this helps!